# Possible to add attendee via api?

Tags: eventbrite

Prior to making an elance job ad, I'm hoping to confirm it's possible to add an attendee to an event via the eventbrite api. As a non-programmer it's not at all clear in reading the dev eventbrite site that this is in fact possible. Here is what I want to do:

1. Create an event in Eventbrite
   (and get the event id or whatever is needed)
2. Create a product in Infusionsoft 
   (using event id from eventbrite)
3. Upon product sale in Infusionsoft, make an http post with information similar to:

http://eventbrite-api-sample.com/ (add attendee command)?(event id command)?(customer name, email, etc)

1. Happily let eventbrite do it's thing in regards to  reminders, checking, followup!

I apologize if my question is obvious! Thanks for any help! If this seems doable my hope is to make an elance job ad and provide the developer resource page for eventbrite!

Ryan

Answer (score 3):

Based on my research and attempts to work with the API, it seems unlikely Eventbrite will ever open up that option. Importing attendees and using API to add attendees is crippled, likely so that no one uses their own site/payment processing to circumvent Eventbrite fees.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is not possible to create a new attendee through the API. Their workflow page also suggests this:

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/workflows/#orders

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently a feature available through the API, but there is an option to add attendees manually through the UI. Instructions are here: http://help.eventbrite.com/customer/en_us/portal/articles/428370-add-attendees-manually

Comment: Why is that ? Wouldn't it make their service 200% relevant for any developers ?